# Can I use a camera sensor from a not functioning smartphone in Arduino or Raspberry pi?

Tags: arduino-mega, camera

I want to use the OmniVision_OV16860 camera sensor from a not functioning Moto G4 plus phone to capture pictures using Arduino or Raspberry Pi.

Is it possible to do that? If yes, explain the whole process.

Comment: For your RPi questions, there is a [RPi stackexchange website](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: 1) remove the camera from the phone .... 2) obtain the data sheet for the camera .... 3) build a connector adapter so that you can plug the camera into a breadboard .... 4) write necessary software to "talk" to the camera

Comment: no, no arduino supports MIPI interfaces, so you have no way to hook it up, and even if you could, there's nowhere near enough ram on an ardunio to store a single image, and there's no way to chuck image data from the camera, so it's simply impossible.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to ... use the OmniVision_OV16860 camera sensor (on an)
>   Arduino?

It is doubtful as bare image sensors usually require specialized software drivers to be of any use. Also, a common Arduino does not have the power to do image processing.  Only the few Arduino's built with unusually powerful processors could handle image processing.  But, at this level, expect little support as most do not do image processing on the Arduino platform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Can you suggest some idea to use this camera  sensor  because the phone is not functioning and i am searching for some cheap and working method to use that camera except of using the sensor in other phone

Comment: If only the cell radio portion of the phone does not work, the easiest way to use the camera is to use it in the Android device.  [Here is a RPi stackexchange question / answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38902/camera-input-from-phone-to-raspberry-pi) where this is discussed.  I have several dead phones and have opted to purchase the cameras specifically intended for the RPi. Again, the powerful features needed to transfer images are not available on common Arduino platforms.